# What is the minimum and maximum size of an Ethernet frame with split up

Tags: networking, ethernet

How do I calculated the minimum and maximum size of an Ethernet frame with split up.We all know maximum size for Ehternet frame is 1518bytes but would be the with split up?

Comment: Are you going to ask us all your interview questions here? We're not averse to helping people answer real questions, but we prefer to not do everything for you. Rather, tell us what you think the answer is (as you did in your broadcast domain question) and we will assist.

Comment: No I'm not to going ask all my interview Questions here.Thanks for answering all my questions

Answer (score 1):

You're referring to IP fragmentation, which is a feature of IP.  IP operates in layer 3, Ethernet in layer 2.

IP can fragment, but Ethernet doesn't know or care about the fragmentation of the IP packets that it's carrying.

Comment: And by the way, if what you're actually interested in is the maximum IP packet size, the answer is 64 KB.

Comment: Thanks for ur response @Shane but I guess maximum and minimum size of ethernet frame 1518 byte and 64byte respectively with split up

Comment: Re-read what he wrote.  There is no notion of fragmentation (or split-up as you seem to call it) in Ethernet.

Comment: Also, the max is not 1518 in all cases see jumbo frames.